# Spring Cloud GCP Datastore - exclude field from being persisted

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, spring-cloud-gcp

I'm using the `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-datastore` dependency in a spring boot application to interface with a Datastore instance in GCP.

I have the following entity mapped out (condensed for brevity):

```
@Entity(name = "order_status")
public class OrderStatus {
    @Id
    @Field(name = "unique_key")
    private String uniqueKey;

    @Field(name = "order_id")
    private String orderId;

    @Field(name = "notification_preferences")
    private NotificationPreferences notificationPreferences;

    //lots of other fields + getters and setters
}
```

When an order event comes into my application, I save the order details in this entity in Datastore. At that time, the `notificationPreferences` field will be `null`.

The application also has an endpoint whose sole purpose is to update the `notificationPreferences` field for an order.

Both pieces of code make changes to the `order_status` entity in Datastore in the same way.

```
OrderStatus orderStatus = repo.findByOrderId(orderId);

//set fields

repo.save(orderStatus);
```

I'm having an intermittent issue when both an order status event and a notification preference update come in at the same time.

The order status event and notification preference update both read the OrderStatus from Datastore with the `notification_preferences` as `null`. The notification preference update code sets the `notification_preferences` value as it should, and then saves that to Datastore via the `repo.save()` call. However, the order status update event code still has `notification_preferences` set to `null` because it read that record from Datastore before the notification preference update finished. So, when the `repo.save()` method is called to update the order status, it sets the `notification_preference` field back to `null`.

So my question is, is there any way to exclude a field from being persisted so that when I call `repo.save()` from the order status update code it would never update the `notification_preferences` field?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to only update specific fields, you'll want to update the entire entity in each path, but you should use a transaction (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.RC2/multi/multi__spring_data_cloud_datastore.html#_transactions_2) in both cases.  That way if there is a concurrent update one will fail, and you'll be able to retry the update attempt.